# How to append records with enforced referential integrity?

Tags: ms-access, foreign-keys, relationship

I have a OCDB table that I use to extract data. I currently use it to append the data to a new table and then manipulate it. The problem is I have just added a relationship to that table and when I use the enforced referential integrity the query won't run.

How do I get the append query to automatically update a foreign key?

Comment: You may not be able to. Can you create a query that includes all the relevant fields, including the key from both tables and is that query updatable? If not, run two queries, one to add the new data t the related table and the other to update the table. This is probably safer.